# Symfony debugbar (web profiler) with composer install issue

Tags: symfony, debugging, profiler

I can't install symfony debugbar (web profiler) with composer. I'm getting an error. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Your package doesn't exist, the message tel you some possibilities.

You can check the "symfony/debug-pack" package https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/debug-pack.